# Custom cell for UICollection view cell unable clear old data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created a custom UICollection cell but the data sometimes appear in the wrong cell and no matter how much I refresh the UICollection view it refuses to change. I have done a print out to see if the data gotten from the array is wrong but it's not. Is there a way to clear the old data from the cell before inputting the next one. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**custom cell**

```
class customAppointmentViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

let thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
    let tniv = UIImageView()
    tniv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tniv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tniv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return tniv
}()

let seperatorView: UIView = {
    let sv = UIView()
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 11, g: 49, b: 68)
    return sv
}()

let clientNamePlaceHolder: UILabel = {
    let fnhp = UILabel()
    fnhp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    fnhp.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 17)
    fnhp.textColor = UIColor.white
    fnhp.textAlignment = .left
    return fnhp
}()

let openingTimePlaceHolder: UILabel = {
    let fnhp = UILabel()
    fnhp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    fnhp.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 12)
    fnhp.textColor = UIColor.white
    fnhp.textAlignment = .left
    return fnhp
}()

let closingTimePlaceHolder: UILabel = {
    let fnhp = UILabel()
    fnhp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    fnhp.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 12)
    fnhp.textColor = UIColor.white
    fnhp.textAlignment = .left
    return fnhp
}()

let bookedBarberNamePlaceHolder: UILabel = {
    let fnhp = UILabel()
    fnhp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    fnhp.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 12)
    fnhp.textColor = UIColor.white
    fnhp.textAlignment = .left
    return fnhp
}()

let servicePricePlaceHolder: UILabel = {
    let fnhp = UILabel()
    fnhp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    fnhp.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 10)
    fnhp.textColor = UIColor.white
    fnhp.textAlignment = .right
    return fnhp
}()

func setupViews(){
    addSubview(thumbnailImageView)
    addSubview(clientNamePlaceHolder)
    addSubview(openingTimePlaceHolder)
    addSubview(closingTimePlaceHolder)
    addSubview(bookedBarberNamePlaceHolder)
    addSubview(servicePricePlaceHolder)
    addSubview(seperatorView)
    backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 23, g: 69, b: 90)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-16-[v0(90)]|", views: thumbnailImageView)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-116-[v0][v1(50)]-10-|", views: clientNamePlaceHolder, servicePricePlaceHolder)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-116-[v0]-60-|", views: openingTimePlaceHolder)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-116-[v0]-60-|", views: closingTimePlaceHolder)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|-116-[v0]-60-|", views: bookedBarberNamePlaceHolder)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-10-[v0(20)][v1(20)][v2(20)][v3(20)]-10-|", views: clientNamePlaceHolder, openingTimePlaceHolder,closingTimePlaceHolder, bookedBarberNamePlaceHolder)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-10-[v0(20)]|", views: servicePricePlaceHolder)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|-10-[v0]-10-[v1(5)]|", views: thumbnailImageView,seperatorView)
    addContraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: seperatorView)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
} 
}
```

**collection view**

```
extension AppointmentsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.appointments.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! customAppointmentViewCell
    //empty cell data
    //real data

    cell.openingTimePlaceHolder.text = ""
    if let opentime = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.bookingStartTimeString {
        cell.openingTimePlaceHolder.text = opentime
    } else {
        cell.openingTimePlaceHolder.text = ""
    }


    cell.closingTimePlaceHolder.text = ""
    if let closetime = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.bookingEndTimeString {
        cell.closingTimePlaceHolder.text = closetime
    } else {
        cell.closingTimePlaceHolder.text = ""
    }


    cell.bookedBarberNamePlaceHolder.text = ""
    if let barberName = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.bookedBarberName {
        cell.bookedBarberNamePlaceHolder.text = barberName
    } else {
        cell.bookedBarberNamePlaceHolder.text = ""
    }


    cell.servicePricePlaceHolder.text = ""
    if let servicepricee = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.bookedServicePrice {
        cell.servicePricePlaceHolder.text = servicepricee
    } else {
        cell.servicePricePlaceHolder.text = ""
    }


    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage()
    if let profileimagess = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.profileImage {
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = profileimagess
    } else {
        cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage()
    }


    cell.clientNamePlaceHolder.text = ""
    if let clientnamess = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.clientName {
        cell.clientNamePlaceHolder.text = clientnamess
    } else {
        cell.clientNamePlaceHolder.text = ""
    }


    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectView.frame.width, height: 100)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let uuidAvail = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "theOriginalBarberShopUUID") as? String{
        if let bookIDDD = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.bookingUniqueID {
            let orderDetail = OrderDetailViewController()
            orderDetail.specificAppintment = self.appointments[indexPath.row]
            orderDetail.barberShopID = uuidAvail
            orderDetail.bookingUniqueIDDD = bookIDDD
            orderDetail.bookedBarberUUIDAX = self.appointments[indexPath.row].bookedBarberUUID
            orderDetail.appointmentsviewhold = self
            orderDetail.indexPathSelected = indexPath.row
            navigationController?.pushViewController(orderDetail, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
}
```

thanks

Comment: in 'customAppointmentViewCell' class do init your all imageview and label in awakeFromNib()

Comment: @Ujesh, I guess Joseph is making cell by purely code and not by xib.

Comment: yes, it's all about code, but he can refresh his subview when every time cell call. so old data will remove when new cell loaded.

Comment: HI @Ujesh yes I am making the cell purely by code. But could you please explain how I can refresh the subviews as I think this might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in `customAppointmentViewCell`

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self. thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage()
    //add here other variable and set default value for all.
}
```

`prepareForReuse` is called when a new cell will show on screen.

And Remove default value set code from your cellForRow as guided by Nikhil Manapure.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks it worked. turns out I was also trying to remove duplicate from the array which prevented it from getting new data upon refreshing the collection view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

Implement the method `prepareForReuse` in your `customAppointmentViewCell` and in this method remove all the data and reset everything. If you are adding some subView to cell in `cellForRow`, remove that too.

By doing this you will be able to reduce this-

```
cell.clientNamePlaceHolder.text = ""
if let clientnamess = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.clientName {
    cell.clientNamePlaceHolder.text = clientnamess
} else {
    cell.clientNamePlaceHolder.text = ""
}
```

to this-

```
if let clientnamess = self.appointments[safe: indexPath.row]?.clientName {
    cell.clientNamePlaceHolder.text = clientnamess
}
```

After doing this, check if the issue is still there.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it removes all the subviews from the collection view and I end up with collection view with empty cells.

Comment: sorry, my bad, added " in `cellForRow`" to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try Passing the model object to the UICollectionViewCell class by assigning a property in cell

example:

UICollectionViewCell:

```
var object: Model? {
  didSet{
    // here do your assignment of text to various labels
  }
}
```

CellForRow:

```
let cell = ...
cell.object = self.appointments[indexPath.item]
return cell
```

I hope this works.

Comment: HI thanks for your reply but unfortunately am getting the same result, with right data appearing in the wrong cell.